# ASP.NET MVC simpler code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code.

```
    <% if (Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something"))
       {%>
          <%: Html.ActionLink("Something1", "Something1", "Home") %>
       <%}else{%>
           <%: Html.ActionLink("Something2", "Something2", "Home") %>
       <%}%>
```

do I really need all those open <% and close %>? Is there a simpler way of writing the same thing?

Comment: I appreciate all the answers with Razor however my project is not using Razon and its too late to convert.

Comment: It's actually not too late to convert.  You don't have to convert every page, you can just do it one page at a time as you work on them.  You can mix aspx and razor pages without problems, although you would need to duplicate your master and layout pages until the conversion was complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% var s = Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something") ? "Something1" : "Something2"; %>
<%: Html.ActionLink(s, s, "Home") %>
```

Or, in Razor:

```
@{ var s = Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something") ? "Something1" : "Something2"; }
@Html.ActionLink(s, s, "Home")
```

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a simpler way: [Razor syntax](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx).

```
@if (Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something"))
{
    Html.ActionLink("Something1", "Something1", "Home");
}
else
{
    Html.ActionLink("Something2", "Something2", "Home");
}
```

But you may need an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the Razor Syntax, although you might need to install some upgrades.

Which would produce code looking like :

```
@if (Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something"))
{
    Html.ActionLink("Something1", "Something1", "Home");
}
else
{
    Html.ActionLink("Something2", "Something2", "Home");
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use Razor views / cshtml  :)

```
@if(Request.Path.ToLower().Contains("something"))
{
    <div> @Html.ActionLink("Something1", "Something1", "Home") </div>
}else {
    <div> @Html.ActionLink("Something2", "Something2", "Home") </div>
}
```